# session id lost when refreshing member page

Tags: php, pdo

I created a memberpage which checks on being logged in and which includes a logout button - see code below. The code for the developed function 'DBLoggedin()' is copied from the site "http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html - section Testing For Logged In Users".

The first time after I login, the memberpage with code below always works when I load it. When I then refresh this page it seems to lose the session id info as it reports 'You must be logged in to access this page'. However, when I remove the 'button onclick' line with the session_destroy() in the code below, the memberpage always works fine.

How should I implement a logout function in the code below such that refreshing the page will not destroy the session info? Or is there anotrher fault in the code that destroys the session info when refreshing?

Please your help. Thank you in advance

The code of memberpage:

```
<?php

/*** begin the session ***/
session_start();

//! include lib after session_start()
include 'test_ecis_lib_pdo.php';

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$mysql_username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$mysql_password = 'xxxxx';

/*** database name ***/
$mysql_dbname = 'xxxx';

if(DBLoggedin($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$mysql_dbname))
{
 echo "<br> still logged in";
}
else
{
 echo "<br> you are not authorised to access this page";
 echo "<br error: ".$message;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Members Only Page</title>


</head>

<body>

<h2><?php echo $message; ?></h2>

<button onclick="<?php Logout();?>"> Logout</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `<?php Logout();?>` is calling session_destroy(). What you should be doing is linking to a logout page, that calls `Logout()`. HTML/JS cannot call PHP functions, they can only call JS functions and load URLs.

```
<button onclick="document.location='/logout.php';"> Logout</button>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
function Logout() {
  session_destroy();
  echo "You have been logged out!";
}

Logout();
```